# What is the fastest program to calculate the first 100 perfect numbers?

Tags: python, numbers

I am a student who is new to programming, especially python. I have tried a program before, but it seems too slow and my computer cannot calculate them. As a reminder, a perfect number is a number equal to half the sum of its divisors (for example, 6 or 28).
Here is my programme

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 0
d = 0
while d < 100:
    while b <= a:
        if a%b ==0:
            c = c + b
        b = b + 1
    if (c - a) == a:
        print(a)
        d = d + 1
    b = 1
    c = 0
```

There are probably some errors, I am just starting to code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider giving your variables names that indicate their meanings.

Comment: You might want to do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of the code. For example, tell your "rubber duck" (or room-mate, family-member, or other suitable alternative) what the variable `a` is used for, and where you modify its value.

Comment: What is the result of running that code?  Please consider posting what you get.

Comment: Also, for-loops exist.

Comment: The first 5 perfect numbers are: 6, 28, 496, 8,128, 33,550,336. This algorithm will run for a very, very long time

Comment: To emphasise how monumental a calculation the first 100 perfect numbers is, wikipedia indicates that only 50 or so Mersenne Primes (from which perfect numbers come) have been discovered, with the largest being at about 10^7 digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Euclid proof](https://brilliant.org/wiki/perfect-numbers/)

```
import math

num = int(input('Enter a Number: '))
sq_num = math.sqrt(num)
primes = []
p_nums = []
for n in range(2, int(sq_num)+1):
   if n > 1:
       for i in range(2, n):
           if (n % i) == 0:
               break
       else:
           primes.append(n)
for i in primes:
    print(i)
    x = math.pow(2, i-1)  * (math.pow(2, i)-1)
    if x < num:
        p_nums.append(int(x))
    else:
        break
print(p_nums)
```

What i'm doing here is getting all prime numbers less than the square root of the number inputed, the reason for this is
*2^(2p−1)*(2^p−1) is always a perfect number, IFF p is a prime number*.
You only need to apply this formula to a few prime numbers and once the value generated (from the calculation) exceeds the inputed number, the loop is terminated. For example, if 100 was inputed, only three prime numbers will be checked before the loop terminates.

Answer (score 1):

I would just change
`while b <= a:`
to `while b <= a/2:`
since there are no divisors after a half of a number